# Embedding GridLayout within RelativeLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am struggling with Kivy in order to make it display buttons properly. I want to create a grid of buttons created in a for loop and display them in a grid inside of RelativeLayout. This results in buttons stack one above the other. Please see below:

Main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_file('TopMenu.kv')
Builder.load_file('BottomMenu.kv')
Builder.load_file('Center.kv')
Builder.load_file('Left.kv')

class mainHolder(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "NAZWA APLIKACJI"
        #return Label(text = "Hello, world")
        return mainHolder()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Main.kv

```
<MainHolder>:
    anchor_x: 'left'
    anchor_y: 'top'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #anchor_x: 'left'
        #anchor_y: 'top'

        TopMenu:
            id: _top_menu
            #size_hint: 1, 0.1
            #height: 0, 1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        Center:
        BottomMenu:
```

center.kv:

```
<Center@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    size_hint: 1, 1
    Left:
    Label:
        text: 'prawa'
```

Left.py:

```
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Left(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Left is alive!")

        for i in range(0, 11):
            print("Adding button: " + str(i))
            but = Button(text="X" + str(i))
            self.add_widget(but)
```

and finally, left.kv:

```
#:import Left Left
<Left>:
    size_hint: 1.3, 1
    pos_hint: 1, 1
```

This approach creates the below:
[image: StackBtns]
I have tried to change RelativeLayout to GridLayout, but then buttons look about the same, with the difference they are on the very bottom left corner, so I guess RelativeLayout is a good way to start to have them positioned in a right place.

So I have added some GridLayout manually inside of Left.kv, as per below:

```
<Left>:
    size_hint: 1.3, 1
    pos_hint: 1, 1

    GridLayout:
        cols: 4
        Button:
            text: "t2"
        Button:
            text: "t2"
        Button:
            text: "t2"
        Button:
            text: "test"
```

And that works just fine. So following on this I have created another class, this time of GridLayout, but that did not work at all - sorry, I do not have the code any longer, deleted it as it was fruitless. Also, having GridLayout added as shown above does not result in add_widget() addint it to the right place. Can you guys help me out? I am seriously frustrated about this and Google does not provide any reasonable answer. I guess this might be wrong approach from the very beginning of this app design, but honestly, I have no idea what the "good" point could be.

---

John Anderson thank you! That works like a charm. I was so close, yet so far, I would have never found this. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a `GridLayout` is a reasonable approach. I have slightly modified your `Left` class to do this:

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Left(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # corrected the call to super
        super(Left, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        print("Left is alive!")

        # set the number of columns in this grid
        self.cols = 5

        for i in range(0, 11):
            print("Adding button: " + str(i))
            but = Button(text="X" + str(i))
            self.add_widget(but)
```